# Android device hang during webservice call

Tags: android

I have a webservice which I have called from my andorid application using httpclient post. 
It works fine from the emulator but when i use my android device samsung s3 debug mode, the device does not response. I have used vpn to access my websercive. In both cases emulator and device vpn is connected.
After long time I get notification myapp is not responding.

It print url and request properly in log.

Code segment in my doBackground method of asyncTask:

```
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);      
    BaseModel model = new BaseModel(requestMsg);

    Log.d("","url: " + url);                
    Log.d("request = ",JsonUtil.toJsonNode(model).toString());              

    httppost.setHeader(CmnConstant.STR_CONT_TYPE, "applicaion/json");
    StringEntity se = new StringEntity(JsonUtil.toJsonNode(model).toString());
    se.setContentEncoding(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "applicaion/json"));
    httppost.setEntity(se);

    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);               
    String resposeMsg = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
```

Comment: Do you have a stack trace that we can look at?

Also, maybe related, it may be 500'ing as the content_type has a typo in it - should be `application/json`

Comment: @Breen Thanks. It works fine from emulator. there is no exception. but prob when i run on my device. It does not print anything after Log.d("","url: " + url);                
Log.d("request = ",JsonUtil.toJsonNode(model).toString());

Comment: So just to confirm, no exceptions are thrown in the ADB view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think problem is for VPN. There is no permission for your device.  try like bellow:

1. Install your application in your device
2. disconnect device from USB
3. Install VPN in your android device
4. connect VPN from your device
5. Test your android application

Hope it will work.